# Can I trigger actions (like mounting a network drive) when I connect to a given network?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

My college offers students some storage space and they make the network path public so that you can connect to it with your laptop once you're on the Wi-Fi network.

For now, I've been keeping a shortcut to my personal folder on my laptop. Obviously, it sits in its folder all day long, school or not, and only works when I'm at school. I was wondering if I could take this approach to the next level and have the drive mounted when I connect to the school's Wi-Fi and unmounted when I disconnect.

Comment: you'd have to write a script to do it, but shouldn't be too rough. you should find some good hints including how to identify the active ssid here: https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/all-about-wifi-networks-and-wifi-adapters-using-the-wmi-and-delphi/ and here for how to configure task scheduler to run it: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/

Comment: @FrankThomas, I was really looking for a builtin solution. If there isn't any, I'm more likely to fall back to the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx) to make one.